# Find and replace recursively

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a folder with tons of folders and files inside it. I would like to do a find and replace for:

- Before: 'my_folder.'
- After: '' (blank)

Here is what I tried (though it didn't work)

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i ‘s/my_folder.//’ {} \;
```

What is the correct command here?

Comment: Make sure to use ascii quotes.

Comment: @David542:  in which way is it failing?  Are you expecting the sed command to rename files, or change something inside them?

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the command you are looking for, is kinda-sorta something like this:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -e "/my_folder./s/my_folder.//" {} \;
```

but all you will get is the output printed on the screen, not written back into the file. In order to accomplish something like that, you should have more than one line of code in my opinion, but again "opinion" being the keyword here. Something like this might help

```
for file in $(find ./ -type -f)
do
  cat ${file} | sed -e "/my_folder./s/my_folder.//" > MyTempFile
  cat MyTempFile > ${file} # use this instead of 'mv' command to preserve file perms
done
```

hope this helps

Comment: Useless use of cat: `sed -e "/my_folder./s/my_folder.//" < $file`